# Interactive Window Runs Slow Constantly When Code Run in Python Interactive

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

On my work laptop the Interactive Window will start and run a couple cells with good speed, but if I run some code within Python Interactive area (PIA = Area with text, "Type code here...") it runs very slow.  At first it reads in a large dataframe fine from my .py file, but I call df.columns in PIA and it takes up to 30 seconds - 1 min.  However, if I call df.columns from within my .py file to the Interactive Window it runs instantaneous.  This happens on other commands as well.  All commands run instantly within python terminal or jupyter notebook.

Python Exetnsion: 2020.1.58038

```
$ python -V  
Python 3.6.10 :: Anaconda, Inc.  
$ conda -V  
conda 4.8.3
```

Visual Studio Code Version: 1.41.1
Windows 10

I'm just trying to figure out if there's a way to speed up the Interactive Window area, so I don't have to keep sending commands over from my .py file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this open issue in github that seemed to fix the issue so far.

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/9596

On March 10 @rchiodo mentioned to enter in VSCode settings -> **Python > Data Science: Run Startup Commands** -> insert...

%config Completer.use_jedi = False