# running big jupyter notebook inside vs code is slow

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have a big jupyter notebook 2MB with 722 cells for developing plotly-dash. Running is slow and run the file doesn't need to create any plot, it will just create a dashboard hyperlink. Even I click on Interrupt to stop running, it still wait a long time before it send interrup signal to notebook. I think it will go through each cell and check each line to make sure it is fine,that is why it is really slow when running. My question is is it possible to only ask vs code to check the code whenever it need for example when plotting, it will check plotting function, etc. I am wondering if there is a way to optimize running time for jupyter notebook. Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62640030/interactive-window-runs-slow-constantly-when-code-run-in-python-interactive, might help, but in general it seems like there are a lot of other users with slow jupyter in vscode and not many answers.

Comment: Thanks scrappedcola, where to find this python run startup command, I cannot find it inside the setting. or how to insert this command %config Completer.use_jedi = False, Thanks

Comment: If you got to preferences > settings and search for "use_jedi" till will bring up the setting. Just make certain the checkbox is unchecked. If you search for Jupyter you can find all the other settings associated with notebooks. Again it's more vscode just not working well with notebooks and not much you can do.

Comment: Thanks Scrappedcola, yes I have already unchecked the box reviously. so it is not related to this issue then.